How to convert hex string to image C# if hex string has odd amount of characters?
So I had an issue where I didn't know how to turn a hex string into a BitmapImage in my WPF app. This almost got solved here: link to question + solution
And I got this script out of it:
public BitmapImage StringToImage(string hex)
{
    int numberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[numberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberChars; i += 2)
    {
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }

    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.EndInit();
        return image;
    }
}

So this works perfectly when the hex has an even amount of characters, but the problem is that sometimes the amount of characters is uneven, then it does not work. The first solution was to add a 0 at the front or end, the front just gave another error, at the back it seemed to work. However now I realized that if I add a 0 at the end of the hex string it only generates half of the image, instead of the whole thing.
Does anyone know how to solve this? It would be amazing if I could get this resolved.

You should never have an odd amount of characters, because each byte has two characters. e.g. 50 bytes -> 100 characters, 51 bytes -> 102 characters. 101 characters is impossible. Instead of trying to generate an image out of an invalid string, maybe you should try to fix the problem why you get this invalid string in the first place?

The obvious conclusion is that your string is (sometimes) incomplete. Which is why it has an odd number of hex digits and generates only half the image. No operations on an incomplete string will produce the right result. You should focus on not getting one.

What is generating this hex string?

This is an assignment, teachers made a database with the hex values in it, and we just have to figure out how to solve it..

I messaged my teacher about it, feel like this isn't really fair cause I wasted a whole day trying to figure this out...

I have a feeling that you convert the image to hex but cannot do it correctly, probably, you don't use the correct format specifier.

I did not, teachers did, I just used their hex value, but I guess that it's solved now, thanks for the help guys!

If hex string has odd amount of characters the hex value is wrong, it just cannot be odd
